# I have made a DC-DC 24 V with a 18-48 V input but it randomly crashes

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

[image]

My DC-DC will randomly crash when delivering 5.5 Amp but it is rated for 6 A, my MCU doesn't heat up.

Comment: You should link to specs for major components in your question.  Not everybody is motivated enough to search for specs and info.  When you say the MCU doesn't heat up, do you mean the LM5176?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Antione Define 'crash', the word crash doesn't reflect any failure modes that I know of. Voltage drops out does. An oscope shot would be appropriate.